# Composite functions in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to use composite functions in Tikz, could you point me to the right syntax?

With a single function, it's working fine:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
        \draw[red, thick, domain=0:8, samples=300] 
        plot (\x, {floor(\bx)}) node[right] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

But as soon as I replace \bx by something else, it doesn't work:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
        \draw[red, thick, domain=0:8, samples=300] 
        plot (\x, {floor({floor(\x/2)})}) node[right] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

It works for me after stripping off the unnecessary braces.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
        \draw[red, thick, domain=0:8, samples=300] 
        plot (\x, {floor(floor(\x/2))}) node[right] {};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I did not try this combination. You saved my day!

Comment: Hello. Please accept the answer so that evryone will know that the subject is closed.